# separate IIS binding for application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, servermanager

I am trying to deploy a website by using program IN IIS 7 using c#.

i want to deploy the application under Default website.

the application should have a different port number (90) that is separate from other applications under Default website or even the default port number of Default website(**i.e., 8080**).

I am trying to do this pro grammatically using **ServerManager** class without specifying any binding information in the **web.config** file of website.

```
static void CreateSite()
    {
        using (ServerManager server = new ServerManager())
        {
            if (server.Sites != null && server.Sites.Count > 0)
            {
                Site defaultsite=server.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Default Web Site");
                if (defaultsite != null)
                {
                    string path = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\";

                    //specify the Binding information
                    string ip = "*";
                    string port = "90";
                    string hostName = "*";


                    string bindingInfo = string.Format(@"{0}:{1}:{2}", ip, port, hostName);
                    defaultsite.Applications.Add("/MyApp", path);

                 server.CommitChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

ServerManager class allows us to create/update/delete bindings for each site rather than for each application under a site as below.

```
                    string ip = "*";
                    string port = "90";
                    string hostName = "*";


                    string bindingInfo = string.Format(@"{0}:{1}:{2}", ip, port, hostName);
                    BindingCollection bindingCollection = defaultsite.Bindings;
                    Binding binding = defaultsite.Bindings.CreateElement("binding");
                    binding["protocol"] = "http";
                    binding["bindingInformation"] = bindingInfo;
                    bindingCollection.Add(binding);
                    server.CommitChanges();
```

How do i specify a different port number for the application in IIS 7.0 using ServerManager class methods?

Answer (score 0):

You  can create a new web site and assign it to a port number of your choice. Under that web site, you can configure your application.

Comment: I have the requirement to deploy the application under default website instead of creating a new site in IIS

Comment: If you host it under default web site, then you can't configure separate port only for that particular application. you can bind a port number for Default web site. then all apps under default web site also listen to the new port.

Comment: otherwise you may try ARR(Application Request Routing) in IIS.